# C# Add value to array through user input

Tags: c#

I want to add elements to my array through a user input.
I know this can be done very easy using a list but i have to use an array.

The problem with the code is that the array.lenght will always be 1. 
I want the array to have the same size as the total amount of elements in it, so
size of the array shouldnt be set when declaring the array.

I thought that if you add an element to an array it will copy the previous values + the added value and create a new array.

UPDATED WITH ANSWER

```
  public static void Add(int x){

     if (Item == null)  // First time need to initialize your variable
     {
         Item = new int[1];
     }
     else
     {
         Array.Resize<int>(ref Item, Item.Length + 1);
     }
     Item[Item.Length-1] = x; //fixed Item.Length -> Item.Length-1
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your question, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @I4V I want to add element to an array through user input. But i want the array to always have the same size as the total amount of elements it contains.

Comment: @Ben you'd have to consantly create a new array of one size greater and then add to the end. The way you are doing it right now is every time you call Add you are create a new array of size one with just your item. Basically you are overwriting the entire array. I know you want to keep the size the exact size of the number of elements. If this is a must, it is going to be very inefficient. Can you make it a set size, ex. 50, and when you reach 50 add another 50 to the size?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Exactly, thats what i need help doing. No i can't set the size to 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test in VS. Here you go:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int[] Item; //Fixed int Item[] to int[] Item
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Add(3);
            Add(4);
            Add(6);
        }


     public static void Add(int x){

         if (Item == null)  // First time need to initialize your variable
         {
             Item = new int[1];
         }
         else
         {
             Array.Resize<int>(ref Item, Item.Length + 1);
         }
         Item[Item.Length-1] = x; //fixed Item.Length -> Item.Length-1
     }

    }
}
```

This should resize your array by one each time and then set the last item to what you are trying to add. Note that this is VERY inefficient.

Comment: @pinkfloyddx33 this only resizes the  array but i doesnt actually add a value right?

Comment: it resizes the array and then sets the last item in the array to your new value

Comment: @pinkfloyddx33 Im getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Ben see my corrections in my edit. I was doing it off the top of my head, didn't bother checking I wrote it right.

Answer (score 1):

Use `List<int>` instead of an explicit array, which will dynamically size for you, and use the Add() method to add elements at the end.

Comment: `I know this can be done very easy using a list but i have to use an array`

Comment: Thanks but I really need to use an array.

Answer (score 0):

Lists grow as you add elements to it. Arrays have a constant size. If you must use arrays, the easiest way to do it, is to create an array that is big enough to hold the entered elements.

```
private int[] _items = new int[100];
private int _count;

public void Add(int x)
{
    _items[_count++] = x;
}
```

You also need to keep track of the number of elements already inserted (I used the field `_count` here);

---

As an example, you can then enumerate all the items like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(_items[i]);
}
```

---

You can make the items accessible publicly like this:

```
public int[] Items { get { return _items; } }

public int Count  { get { return _count; } }
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to grow the array size automatically, this is best done by doubling the actual size, when the array becomes too small. It's a good compromise between speed and memory efficiency (this is how lists work internally).

```
private int[] _items = new int[8];
private int _count;

public void Add(int x)
{
   if (_count == _items.Lengh) {
       Array.Resize(ref _items, 2 * _items.Length);
   }
    _items[_count++] = x;
}
```

However, keep in mind that this changes the array reference. So no permanent copy of this array reference should be stored anywhere else.